# Invalid Type :Error

Tags: apex

I want to capture the error in one of the fields for that first I have to get the error using getmessage() method.but when iterating in for loop getting the error
invalid type error

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
Contact con = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
Id oppId = opp.Id;
Id contactId = con.Id;
String unrendered = 'Dear {!Opportunity.StageName},\n Hope you\'re doing well!';
List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> renderResults = Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(contactId, oppId, new List<String>{unrendered});
if(renderResults !=null){
    if (!renderResults[0].isSuccess()) {    
        for (Error err : renderResults[0].getErrors()) {
            System.debug('Error message========='+err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message you are getting (copy/paste it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through the wrong type. The [`getErrors()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Messaging_RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult.htm) method returns a `List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateError>`:

> **getErrors()**
>
> If an error occurred during the renderEmailTemplate method, a RenderEmailTemplateError object is returned.
>
> **Signature**
>
> ```
> public List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateError> getErrors()
> ```

So **you need to change the type for your loop variable to `Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateError`**:

```
for (Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateError error : renderResults.getErrors())
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you're trying to use Visualforce tags within APEX and that doesn't work:

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
Contact con = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
Id oppId = opp.Id;
Id contactId = con.Id;
String unrendered = 'Dear ' + opp.StageName + ',\n Hope you\'re doing well!';
List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> renderResults = Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(contactId, oppId, new List<String>(unrendered));
if(renderResults !=null){
    if (!renderResults[0].isSuccess()) {    
        for (Error err : renderResults[0].getErrors()) {
            System.debug('Error message=========' + err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Another note, you're addressing your message to the opportunity's stage name? Maybe try:

```
String unrendered = 'Dear ' + con.FirstName + ' ' + con.LastName + ',\n Hope you\'re doing well!';
```

Don't forget to add those new fields to your query.

**Update:**

[Looks like you're using the wrong type in your for loop:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Messaging_RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult.htm)

```
for (Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateError err : renderResults[0].getErrors())
```

Try that.

[Also, reference for the error type so you know what methods are available and how to access the error message.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Messaging_RenderEmailTemplateError.htm#apex_class_Messaging_RenderEmailTemplateError)

Comment: for (Error err : renderResults[0].getErrors()) {       iam facing issue in this line...no merge field format is working i have checked in debug logs

Comment: @sarithasari Updated my answer

Comment: @sarithasari Please don't forget to vote up and accept the answer if it solves your needs.

Comment: Toby - please see this [Meta post](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed/2128#2128) re: soliciting for up votes (community etiquette issue)